# Search Tool for Linux similar with Google Desktop

Tags: linux, search

I have a huge project with thousands of lines of code.
I need to search in it and the IDE I'm using has to search each file at the time for the pattern I need.

Is there a GUI tool I can use that makes a local index and makes the search much faster ? I need to search for php code so syntax like $var must work.

PS : google desktop is good but is not working well with exact php syntax search.

Comment: belongs to superuser.com

Comment: If you are programming in one of the languages supported by ctags or cscope you can try that.

Answer (score 1):

Try GNU Global (http://www.gnu.org/software/global/).  It'll create an index and allow you to do funky things like:

```
less -t functionName
```

To display the description of the function you are after.  See the [tutorial](http://www.gnu.org/software/global/manual/global.html) for more cool stuff!